# Kettle Table Input - Problemas obteniendo información de Base de datos (DatabaseMetaInformation.getData)

Tags: pentaho

Tengo una instalación de Pentaho Data Integration 9 en un CentOS 8 utilizando repositorio en sistema de ficheros.

En un Table Input, si pulso en el botón "Get SQL select statement..." para que me muestre las tablas de la conexión, me aparece el siguiente error: *Unable to retrieve database information because an error*

Este error no me aparece si no me conecto al repositorio, mostrándome correctamente las tablas de la Base de Datos.

¿Sabéis a qué puede deberse?
Gracias!

[image: Get SQL select statement...]